# Direction Determination Algorithm Mixes Left and Right

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm working on an algorithm that determines the direction of an edge BC relative to an edge AB.

I have implemented ArcCos determination. It almost works. It correctly determines forward and correctly determines when a turn is needed. But does not correctly determine if it is a right or left turn.

```
private Direction DetermineDirectionOfV2(Vertex v1, Vertex v2, Vertex v3)
{
    if (v1 == null || v2 == null || v3 == null)
        return Direction.Forward;

    double p12 = v1.distance2D(v2);
    double p13 = v1.distance2D(v3);
    double p23 = v2.distance2D(v3);

    double p12S = p12 * p12;
    double p13S = p13 * p13;
    double p23S = p23 * p23;

    double a = p12S + p13S - p23S;
    double b = 2 * p12 * p13;

    if(b == 0.0)
         return Direction.Forward;

    double angle = Math.Acos(a / b);

    double thresh = 0.1;
    if(angle >= -thresh && angle <= thresh)
    {
        return Direction.Forward;
    }
    else if (angle > 0 && angle < Math.PI)
    {
        return Direction.Right;
    }
    else
    {
        return Direction.Left;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I think it might be that this will tell me the angle ABC instead of the angle of BC relative to AB.

In a left turn situation, I get around 1.1 radians for the angle which is wrong. It should be at least > 3.14 radians or -1.1 radians.

What could be wrong?

These 3 verticies:

```
//x,y,z  (z is unused)
            v1 = new Vertex(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,"");
            v2 = new Vertex(0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f, "");
            v3 = new Vertex(5.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f, "");
```

give an angle of 0.46 radians when in fact it should be 4.71238898 rad because from the perspective of AB, BC forms a 270 degree angle.

Thanks

Example

If we have points that look like this:

```
A


B       C
```

This should yield 270 degrees or 4.7rad because if we walk from A to B, we will turn left to get to C.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use Atan in this case, could you give me an example?

Comment: you need to use atan2, not atan

Comment: @Seb I'm not sure what the Y and X parameters would be in this case. Would it be a and b variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have the signs of your numerator wrong. The Cosine Rule is

```
c² = a² + b² - 2*a*b*cos(alpha)
```

Hence,

```
cos(alpha) = (c² - a² - b²) / (2 * a * b)
```

which in your nomenclature means:

```
angle = Math.Acos(p13S - p12S - p23S / (2 * p12 * p13));
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't solve your problem.

The Cosine Rule gives the smallest angle between the two cathetes. You work only on lengths, so you lose the direction information. The `acos` function returns angles in the range from 0 to π, but you need the whole circle from -π to π.

Your question does not make this clear, but I guess that you have two-dimensional vectors in the x,y plane. (Without a reference plane, directions like left and right don't make sense.)

If that is so, you can determine whether you turn left or right by calculating the cross product of AB and BC. Then check the sign of the z component:

```
private Direction dir(Vertex v1, Vertex v2, Vertex v3)
{
    double ax = v2.x - v1.x;
    double ay = v2.y - v1.y;
    double bx = v3.x - v2.x;
    double by = v3.y - v2.y;

    double z = ax*by - ay*bx;

    if (z > 0.0) return Direction.Left;
    if (z < 0.0) return Direction.Right;
    return Direction.Forward;
}
```

The checks for `0.0` should of course be made with a suitable threshold, as in your original code. That threshold depends on the lengths of the vectors, however, because:

```
|a x b| = |a| * |b| * sin(angle)
```

Also, the direction Forward will also apply to Backward. If you want to distinguish between those directions, you can check whether the scalar product

```
ax*bx + ay*by
```

is positive (Forward) or negative (Backward).